# Xcode 6 ViewController content is smaller than the simulator screen

Tags: objective-c, iphone, storyboard, ios7.1, xcode6.1.1

i'm developing app for both IOS7 & IOS8, and using storyBoard with size classes enabled.

app works fine in all simulators from iPhone 4s IOS7 to iPhone 6+ 
but the viewController is smaller than the screen in iPhone 5 with iOS7

[image]

app supports different orientations, i tried and canceled orientations but didn't work. i rested the simulator content, didn't work. I tried to change the initial view controller, didn't work. I cleaned the project, didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your application in fullscreen in iPhone5 you must provide Launch Image for iPhone5 with resolution `640x1136`.

If you are not including Launch Image of the size iPhone5 require then app will run in the centre of the screen, showing black area at top and bottom.

You can also refer [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33150/how-to-update-your-apps-for-the-4-inch-iphone-5-display) for more information.

Comment: thanx :) , it works now, but feels stupid :s, i was postponing putting design + images to later.... Xcode showed error: says put launch screen, but i didn't think that launch screen will cause this problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a `Default-568@2x.png` in the supporting files